# Hbase on windows error

Tags: windows, hbase

While starting hbase I'm getting the following error.

```
$ ./bin/start-hbase.sh
cygpath: can't convert empty path
cygpath: can't convert empty path
: Name or service not knownstname 127.0.0.1
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase-1.3.1/bin/../logs/hbase-xxx-master-xxx.out
cygpath: can't convert empty path
starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase-1.3.1/bin/../logs/hbase-premkumar.k-1-regionserver-XXXX.out
cygpath: can't convert empty path
```

What I need's to look at it for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cygwin to install Hbase

About this error "Name or service not knownstname 127.0.0.1",
try to start ssh in Cygwin Terminal

```
$ net start sshd

$ ssh localhost
```

I also didn't find the reason about this error "cygpath: can't convert empty path".

Additionally, The versions above 0.96 support a script named "start-hbase.cmd" for Windows. You can run it in CMD without Cygwin.

Hope this helps.